# The colors on the left and right sides of the status bar are different

Tags: ios, iphone

Has anyone ever had a similar problem
Xcode 11.4.1
iOS13.4.1

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhEOg.png)

Comment: can you show complete screenshot?
It seems like u have safeArea contraints issue.

Comment: Add a complete screenshot and describe an issue as well.